# Solutions of $x^2+y^2+z^2 = n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have to prove that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2 = n$ only has a solution in the 2-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_2$ if and only if $n \neq 4^m(8k+7)$, with $k,m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. In the previous exercises, I already showed that this equation has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all odd primes by using the multivariate Hensel-Rychlik lemma but I have no clue how I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\equiv 1,2,3,5,6\pmod8$ there's an integer
solution to $x^2+y^2+z^2\equiv n\pmod 8$
with $x$ odd. Then $n-y^2-z^2$ is an integer congruent to $1$ modulo $8$,
and so is a $2$-adic square, $x'^2$. Then $x'^2+y^2+z^2=n$ over $\Bbb Z_2$.

If $4\mid n$ consider $n/4$ etc.

Comment: It's not really clear to me why something congruent to 1 mod 8 has to be a 2-adic square. Can you explain this?

Comment: @DriesBeheydt It's an application of Hensel's lemma, and is in all the text-books.